# Picamera record videos to different files error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am using Picamera V3 to record a series of videos and store them in a series files. For example, I record 5 videos and each of them is 2s. I store them in files1 to files5. Please see the following code:

```
import os
from io import BytesIO
from time import sleep
import picamera
from datetime import datetime

""" initialization """
destination = '/home/pi/Desktop/video'

stop = 0

""" camera setup """
camera=picamera.PiCamera()

camera.sharpness = 0
camera.contrast = 0
camera.brightness = 50
camera.saturation = 0
camera.ISO = 0
camera.video_stabilization = False
camera.exposure_compensation = 0
camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
camera.meter_mode = 'average'
camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
camera.image_effect = 'none'
camera.color_effects = None
camera.rotation = 0
camera.hflip = False
camera.vflip = False
camera.crop = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
camera.resolution=(1024,768)

""" datetime get """
now = datetime.now()

""" file name def """
def get_file_name():
    return os.path.join(destination, \
                        "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s %d.h264" \
                        %(now.year, now.month, \
                          now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, i))

# start loop 
while(stop==0):

    if stop==1:
        camera.stop_recording()
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close

    else:
        for i in range(1,5):
            # open file
            filename = get_file_name()
            video_file = open(filename,'wb')

            #start recording
            camera.start_preview()
            camera.start_recording(video_file)
            sleep(2)

            if i==4:
                stop = 1
                break
```

When I run this code:
1, I can only get 2 files rather than 5
2, I will get the error: "The camera is already using port 1"
What can I do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: use wait_recording to catch exceptions (for example out of memory in disk) hope it helps http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/_modules/picamera/camera.html#PiCamera.wait_recording

Comment: btw, change to range(0,5) to iterate 5 times, range(1,5) will iterate 4 times

Comment: Hi, I tried wait_recording. It gave the same errors. A

Answer (score 0):

I make some changes to the while loop and now I would like to check from keyboard input after each recording.

```
import os
from io import BytesIO
from time import sleep
import picamera
from datetime import datetime

""" initialization """
destination = '/home/pi/Desktop/video'
i = 0
stop = 0

""" camera setup """
camera=picamera.PiCamera()

camera.sharpness = 0
camera.contrast = 0
camera.brightness = 50
camera.saturation = 0
camera.ISO = 0
camera.video_stabilization = False
camera.exposure_compensation = 0
camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
camera.meter_mode = 'average'
camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
camera.image_effect = 'none'
camera.color_effects = None
camera.rotation = 0
camera.hflip = False
camera.vflip = False
camera.crop = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
camera.resolution=(1024,768)

""" datetime get """
now = datetime.now()

""" file name def """
def get_file_name():
    return os.path.join(destination, \
                        "%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s %d.h264" \
                        %(now.year, now.month, \
                          now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, i))

# start loop 
while(stop == 0):
#while(True):

    i = i + 1
    # open file
    filename = get_file_name()
    video_file = open(filename,'wb')

    #start recording
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording(video_file)
    sleep(2)

    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.stop_preview()

    video_file.close()

    stop = raw_input("input 1 to stop or 0 continue\n")

else:
    camera.close()
    print ("Done!")
```

Now I find there is still something wrong:
1, No matter 1 or 0 I input, the program will show "Done!" and exit the while loop.
2, Is there a way I can use to fulfill the function that: if I type a "1" the recording stops and exit the while loop ,or the loop will keep going.
Thank you.